# On record edit, fields value are not populating on modal

Tags: lightning, update

when click on the edit button modal is showing and in that modal fields values are not populating when i check debug and console.log record id is showing and set the contact value in attribute.

Apex Controller

```
public class EditContactController {


@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> UpdateContact(String conid) {
    system.debug('conid'+conid);
       return [Select Id,firstname,lastname,email from Contact where id=:conid];

 }
}
```

**Lightning Component**

```
  <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="EditContactController" >


<aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute type="Contact[]" name="EditContact" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'Contact' }"></aura:attribute>



<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                          onclick="{! c.CloseDialog}"
                                          alternativeText="close"
                                          variant="bare-inverse"
                                          class="slds-modal__close"/>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Edit Contact</h2>
                </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.EditContact}" var="conn"> 

                            <div class="row">
                                <lightning:input name="InputFirsname" label="First Name" value="{!conn.Firstname}"/>
                                <lightning:input name="InputLastname" required="true" label="LastName" value="{!conn.Lastname}"/>
                                 <lightning:input name="InputEmail" label="Email" value="{!conn.Email}"/>
                             </div>
                        </aura:iteration> 

                </div> 


                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button variant="neutral" 
                                      label="Cancel"
                                      title="Cancel"
                                      onclick="{! c.CloseDialog }"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" 
                                      label="Save"
                                      title="Save"
                                      onclick="{!c.SaveRecord}"/>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>

    </aura:if>
 </aura:component>
```

**Lightning Component Controller**

```
 ({

Edit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isOpen", true);
    console.log('Edit record ID..'+event.target.id);
    var RecordId = event.target.id;
    var action = component.get("c.UpdateContact");
    action.setParams({ conid: RecordId });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if(response.getState()==="SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
            alert(response.getState());
            alert('log-->'+response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.EditContact",response.getReturnValue());
            //console.log('rec-->'+rec);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);



},
CloseDialog : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isOpen", false);

},
SaveRecord : function(component, event, helper){

    //component.set("v.RecordId",)


}

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the model popup once you get the data.

```
Edit : function(component, event, helper) {
    //component.set("v.isOpen", true);
    console.log('Edit record ID..'+event.target.id);
    var RecordId = event.target.id;
    var action = component.get("c.UpdateContact");
    action.setParams({ conid: RecordId });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if(response.getState()==="SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
            alert(response.getState());
            alert('log-->'+response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.EditContact",response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.isOpen", true); // add this line after you populate and not before that.
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

Comment: only i am getting email id. firstname and lastname showing blank why

Comment: @cloudZigZag check you have proper data there.

Comment: yes proper data there firstname,lastname,email everything is there. and one more thing i am working on contact object and in this obj lastname is required so without lastname contact presence is nothing.

Comment: @cloudZigZag can you try `FirstName and LastName` as they are case sensitive.

Comment: yes got it thanks +1